# Is it possible to package Gradle scripts as a plugin into a Jar

Tags: gradle

I need to distribute a Gradle plugin among several repositories and would like to package it as a jar, or at least a single artifact. I can write all of the functionality in straight Gradle and would prefer to over writing Groovy. Is it possible to package Gradle files together that can be used as a Gradle plugin via 'apply'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, build scripts can only be distributed via HTTP (`apply from: "http://..."`). However, a binary plugin (i.e. a class implementing the `org.gradle.api.Plugin` interface) can use almost the same syntax as a build script, and can be distributed as a Jar.